# How to increment two different build numbers in TeamCity

Tags: build, teamcity

In my project, I have a version number and a revision number. Version number is in Julian date format and incremented everyday when revision number is incremented with every build within a day. 
For example in May 12 => 133.1, 133.2 and etc 
in May 13 => 134.1, 134.2 and etc.

I can create two build configurations that increments each but I am not sure how to access the other build configurations parameter.

My current version format is %VersionJulDateBuildNum%.%build.counter%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one build configuration has a snapshot dependency to the other one, you can reference it's parameters using **%dep.**

[image]
[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: This is what I was looking for, Thank you! . I also need a way to reset the revision number for the next build after the nightly build. Is there any way to do this without powershell ?

Comment: all you need to do is save this "next.build=1" to the .properties file of the project in <TeamCityData>\config\projects\ProjectName\buildNumbers\something.buildNumbers.properties. TBH, if you had a build config that was triggered nightly, that was dependent on the actual build running, you could then run a step afterwards to rewrite the contents of the properties file.

Comment: I found the properties file, Thank you. What is this best way to modify this file and set next.build=1 ? Is there anyway to do this besides creating a build step that executes a powershell script which looks at the file and does a find and replace? Because that's what I can think of.

Comment: "next.build=1" | Out-File "D:\Files\buildNumbers.properties" would be the simplest

Answer (score 0):

TeamCity will automatically manage the AssemblyVersion attributes for you, but there are a few caveats:

It will totally overwrite the existing value.
It will update all AssemblyVersions in the solution, so if you are tied to keeping different project versions in the same solution, this may not work for you.
With those caveats, here's how we've set it up:

In the General Settings of your build configuration, change the Build number format to %version%.{0}
In your Build Parameters define %version% as your major.minor.patch.
In your Build Steps, scroll to the bottom of the screen and click Add Build Feature. Select AssemblyInfo patcher. Make sure the Assembly version format is filled in as %build.number%.
And that's it. TeamCity will update all your assembly infos to major.minor.patch.build as defined by the %version% and build counter, and then automatically revert those changes as the very last step of the build.

Comment: I have seen this answer before in other post. This does not address what I am asking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "easy" (or built-in) way to do that with TeamCity.

A common approach I've seen before is to have a Powershell (or Bash) script step in the beginning of the build (which you can put on a template that all builds can inherit from) that will read the version number from a text file somewhere (e.g. network share that all build agents can see), increment it, and update the file. You can use the build configuration ID, which is unique, to name the file.

Another approach, more complex but more elegant (IMO), is to store the version number as a parameter of the build configuration itself, and then via steps in the build, use the TeamCity REST API to update the parameter with the incremented value. That way you are using TeamCity to store the value for you and don't have to worry about network shares, text files, file locks, etc.

---

Not really related to your question, but I'd recommend you take a look at [SemVer](http://semver.org) if you haven't already as an alternative for the versioning scheme your using, which (IMO) gives you more valuable information.